# Package quantmod, function getMetals, unexpected error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r, quantmod

A few days ago the following code worked:

```
getMetals('silver', from = '1900-01-01')
```

Yesterday and today I have tried all of the following:

```
getMetals('silver', from = '1900-01-01')
getMetals('silver')
getMetals('XAG')
```

I also tried using getSymbols, without being sure about the symbol:

```
getSymbols('XAGUSD', src = 'oanda')
```

In all cases I get the following error message: `Error in charToDate(x): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`.

I have checked my sessionInfo() - not sure this helps - and it runs quantmod_0.4-7.

Thank you!

Comment: The oanda source data page has been very unstable recently and shows `Error 404 page not found`, this is the reason behind the error you encountered, you can confirm by trying `debug(getMetals);getMetals('silver', from = '2017-01-01')`

Comment: Joshua Ulrich - quantmod, has provided a fix for this problem on his GitHub page. I haven't tested it, but there's a good set of comments and additional workarounds that I hope will provide a solution: [link] https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/144